# ASP.NET Web Application -> Windows Authentication -> IIS Express -> Kerberos or NTLM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

Creating a new ASP.NET Web Application with Windows Authentication the description only says "For intranet applications". The Learn more link leads to the site below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth

Description there is the following:

> **Windows Authentication**
>
> If you select Windows Authentication, the sample application will be
>   configured to use the Windows Authentication IIS module for
>   authentication. The application will display the domain and user ID of
>   the Active directory or local machine account that is logged into
>   Windows but won't include user registration or log-in UI. This option
>   is intended for Intranet web sites.
>
> Alternatively, you can create an Intranet site that uses AD
>   authentication by choosing the On-Premises option under Organizational
>   Accounts. The On-Premises option uses Windows Identity Foundation
>   (WIF) instead of the Windows Authentication module. Some additional
>   steps are required in order to set up the On-Premises option, but WIF
>   enables features that aren't available with the Windows Authentication
>   module. For example, with WIF you can configure application access in
>   Active Directory and query directory data.

However what I can't find out is whether the solution uses `NTLM` or `Kerberos` authentication? Also is there some way that I can toggle this in IIS Express? I tried to look at the requests in Chrome network tab but I did not get any information from there.

[image]

Comment: Windows Auth uses Active directory which based on my understanding just uses your domain's login. That's why you can't access it from the internet. you need vpn for it

Comment: @Steve Nope, I can still use it on a computer not attached to active directory. See Microsoft description above: `The application will display the domain and user ID of the Active directory OR local machine`. And my question about `NTLM` or `Kerberos` remains. :)

Comment: If you are voting down, please say why!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using Fiddler to look at the requests and from there I could see that it was `NTLM` due to the extra round trip to authenticate the client.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tristank/2006/08/02/two-easy-ways-to-pick-kerberos-from-ntlm-in-an-http-capture/

I did not find any good way to enable `Kerberos` for IIS Express but using the normal IIS you can follow this guide:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/

Authentication flow:

Request:

```
GET http://localhost:44388/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44388
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 21:26:40 GMT
Content-Length: 6137
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Request 2:

```
GET http://localhost:44388/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44388
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Negotiate YIGCBgYrBgEFBQKgeDB2oDAwLgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCgYJKoZIgvcSAQICBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIGCisGAQQBgjcCAh6iQgRATlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4gkACQA3AAAADwAPACgAAAAKANc6AAAAD0RFU0tUT1AtSEFLR0xTQldPUktHUk9VUA==
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Response 2:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYIBCzCCAQegAwoBAaEMBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKooHxBIHuTlRMTVNTUAACAAAAHgAeADgAAAAVworiD/awyYeVbOYA0680pgIAAJgAmABWAAAACgDXOgAAAA9EAEUAUwBLAFQATwBQAC0ASABBAEsARwBMAFMAQgACAB4ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAEgAQQBLAEcATABTAEIAAQAeAEQARQBTAEsAVABPAFAALQBIAEEASwBHAEwAUwBCAAQAHgBEAEUAUwBLAFQATwBQAC0ASABBAEsARwBMAFMAQgADAB4ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAEgAQQBLAEcATABTAEIABwAIADPF56zsodMBAAAAAA==
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 21:26:40 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Request 3:

```
GET http://localhost:44388/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44388
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UTE1TU1AAAwAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAABXCiOIKANc6AAAAD2wKVsUToYhrt08pUPhmI2WjEgQQAQAAAGDLpB1QQ6YlAAAAAA==
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Response 3:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAACHgwE6ErQtUAAAAAA=
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 21:26:40 GMT
Content-Length: 397
```

Comment: If you are voting down, please say why!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly, but if you read the first response `Authorization: Negotiate` header,

> YIGCBgYrBgEFBQKgeDB2oDAwLgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCgYJKoZIgvcSAQICBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIGCisGAQQBgjcCAh6iQgRATlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4gkACQA3AAAADwAPACgAAAAKANc6AAAAD0RFU0tUT1AtSEFLR0xTQldPUktHUk9VUA==

Convert to ASCII and if it contains `NTLMSSP`, then it is NTLM.
Like this...

```
`??  +     ?x0v?00. 
+    ?7  
  *?H??      *?H??     
+    ?7   ?B @NTLMSSP     ?? ?    7       (   
 ?:    DESKTOP-HAKGLSBWORKGROUP
```

Comment: Convert to ASCII and if it contains NTLMSSP, then it is NLTM.

Comment: True, I saw this as well but due to the fact that an extra request was made I could already tell it was NTLM.